# Issues with log function coding

Tags: rstudio, logarithm, derivative, economics

I am new at R studio and I am trying to solve the following issues

I have a function that basically is

## Profit = Revenue - Advertisement spent

## Once revenue is based on how much I spend we can rewrite such as Profit = F(Ad_spend) - Ad_spend

Based on the log curve line the coeff is below as follow:

Log equation
-507.3997+193.0983*log(x) - x

I am having issues to write this function and I need to have my derivative based on that and find out what is the Ad_spend that maximize my profit.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working? 
Using "-507.3997+193.0983*log(x) - x" as is, works for me.

Comment: Hey Mortom sorry for not being specific enough.                                                  
  Profit = function(x)
          {x = -507.3997+193.0983*log(x)-x
          return(x)} - What I meant was how can I derive this function and view the result ? I need to present that to my manager to explain that Ad_spend that maximize profit based on this function is 192,09

Comment: Oh, Okay, Thats simple then. If this formula is set in stone you can derive it by hand element wise - meaning d/dx (-507.3997+193.0983*log(x) - x) = d/dx(-507.3997)+d/dx(193.0983*log(x)) - d/dx(x) = 0 + 193.0983*1/(ln(10) * x) - 1. Note that the ln(10)) come from base 10 logarithm. if you use something else you gotta change it accordingly